# Prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\,\int_{-nT/2}^{nT/2}f(x)\,dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\,n\int_o^Tf(x)\,dx$

Tags: calculus, limits, improper-integrals

Prove that for a periodic function $f$ with fundamental period $T$, the following equality holds

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\,\int_{-nT/2}^{nT/2}f(x)\,dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\,n\int_o^Tf(x)\,dx$$

I think that I should start by decomposing the first integral into a sum of integrals, something like

$$\left[\dots+\int_{-\infty T/2}^{\infty T/2}f\,dx+\dots+\int_{-(n+1)T/2}^{(n+1)T/2}f\,dx+\int_{-nT/2}^{nT/2}f\,dx \right]$$ but I don't know if I'm doing it correctly. How do I get $n\int f(x)\,dx$ from the above relation? Is there a better way to prove this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-nT/2}^{nT/2}f(x)\phantom{.}dx&=\int_{-nT/2}^{0}f(x)\phantom{.}dx+\int_{0}^{nT/2}f(x)\phantom{.}dx\\
\\
&=\int_{-nT/2+nT}^{0+nT} f(x)\phantom{.}dx+\int_{0}^{nT/2}f(x)\phantom{.}dx\\
\\
&=\int_{nT/2}^{nT}
f(x)\phantom{.}dx+\int_{0}^{nT/2}f(x)\phantom{.}dx\\
\\
&=\int_{0}^{nT}f(x)\phantom{.}dx\\
\\
&=n\int_{0}^{T}f(x)\phantom{.}dx
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ has period $T$ then it has the same integral over any interval of length $nT$. Hence the integral on the left can be written as $\int_0^{nT}f(x)dx$ which can be split into integrals from $0$ to $T$, $T$ to $2T$ and so on. So the integral is exactly equal to $n\int_0^{T} f(x) dx$.